# Sending onMouseDown from parent to child

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to send the clickevent from the parent to the child?

This is my parent component:

```
<Component {...props}>
     <Child />
     {props.children}
</Component>
```

This is the child component:

```
<Component onMouseDown={e => this.handleClick(e, props)}></Component>
```

Whenever the parent component is clicked I want to trigger the handleclick component of my child.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean from child to parent?

Comment: I guess you need another function in the parent, send it as a props in your child and the in the child you can call `this.props.myParentFunc()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to your child component:

```
// parent.js

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.child = React.createRef();
}

handleMouseDown = e => {
  this.child.current.handleClick(e, this.props);
}

render() {
  return (
    <Component onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown} {...props}>
       <Child ref={this.child}/>
       {props.children}
    </Component>
  )
}
```

Comment: I get the error "TypeError: this.child.current.handleClick is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using rxjs with Observable and Subscriptions.  Here is a working example and I'll explain what's going on https://codesandbox.io/s/7wjwnznk3j

Relevant reading:

- fromEvent: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent
- subscription: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subscription

I used Typescript since I prefer it, but is absolutely not a requirement.  You parent class will look like this:

```
interface State {
  obs$?: Observable;
}

class App extends React.Component<null, State> {
  public readonly state: State = {};
  public ref: React.Ref<React.ReactHTMLElement>;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      obs$: fromEvent(this.ref, 'click')
    });
  }

  @Bind()
  setParentRef(el: HTMLElement) {
    this.ref = el;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={parentStyles} ref={this.setParentRef}>
        <Child parentClick={this.state.obs$} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

We have our ref `this.ref` and set it through the function, we need this since it is the target of a `fromEvent` and `click` is the event.  This automatically creates an observable that will emit to any subscribers when it is clicked.  You will want to pass this as a prop to your child component.  Then in that component you can subscribe to it and do whatever you want when there is a click in the parent.

```
interface Props {
  parentClick?: Observable;
}

interface State {
  onClick$?: Subscription;
  numClicks: number;
}

class Child extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  public readonly state: State = { numClicks: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.parentclick) {
      this.handle();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props) {
    if (
      this.props.parentClick !== undefined &&
      this.state.onClick$ === undefined
    ) {
      this.handleSubscribe();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.state.onClick$) {
      this.state.onClick$.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  handleSubscribe() {
    this.setState({
      onClick$: this.props.parentClick.subscribe(this.onParentClick)
    });
  }

  @Bind()
  onParentClick() {
    this.setState((prevState: State) => ({
      numClicks: prevState.numClicks + 1
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={childStyles}>
        Parent clicked {this.state.numClicks} time(s)
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So in this instance, when the parent is clicked the subscription invokes the `onParentClick` method.  Then in that method we implement a simple counter and display it in the HTML.

One thing important thing is to ALWAYS make sure you unsubscribe from subscriptions.  If you don't this will create a memory leak and will be really tricky to track down, since it is easy to overlook.